# admin.py completely ignored when app is in: /myvenv/myproject/apps/myapp/

Tags: python, django

Recently I upgraded my project to latest Django (from 1.8 to 1.11.4) and my models don’t show up anymore in the Django Admin interface. The weird thing is that the app itself works as expected.

The full path **/myvenv/myproject/apps/myapp/**

A part of the structure:

```
/myvenv/
  /bin
  /etc
  /myproject
    /templates
    /settings/settings.py
    /apps
      /myapp
        /templates/myapp/myview.html
        /views.py
```

Some other symptoms:

- 'manage runserver' also misses this file for auto reload
- My custom management commands in that app are unknown since the update

nb: The 'myproject' is actually called 'project' (clash?)

When forcing import from **/myvenv/myproject/apps/myapp/__init__.py/**

```
from .admin import *
```

it breaks on the first admin.site.register() with:

```
LookupError at /admin/
No installed app with label 'myapp'.
```

I’ve:

- disabled as much as possible in the settings file
- removed all (old) admin autodiscover code
- disabled as much imports as possible (cleaning redundancy)
- added 'django.setup()’ recently to settings, but not sure after/before what settings it should go.

Installed apps (seen from manage shell):

```
<module 'django.contrib.auth' from '/srvapp/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/contrib/auth/__init__.pyc'>
<module 'django.contrib.contenttypes' from '/srvapp/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/contrib/contenttypes/__init__.pyc'>
<module 'django.contrib.sessions' from '/srvapp/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/contrib/sessions/__init__.pyc'>
<module 'django.contrib.messages' from '/srvapp/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/contrib/messages/__init__.pyc'>
<module 'django.contrib.staticfiles' from '/srvapp/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/contrib/staticfiles/__init__.pyc'>
<module 'django.contrib.sites' from '/srvapp/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/contrib/sites/__init__.pyc'>
<module 'bootstrap3' from '/srvapp/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/bootstrap3/__init__.pyc'>
<module 'django.contrib.admin' from '/srvapp/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/contrib/admin/__init__.pyc'>
<module 'django.contrib.admindocs' from '/srvapp/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/contrib/admindocs/__init__.pyc'>
<module 'myapp' from '/srvapp/project/apps/myapp/__init__.pyc'>
```

The init's:

```
 /myvenv/myproject# find . -name __init__.py
./__init__.py
./apps/__init__.py
./apps/myapp/tests/__init__.py
./apps/myapp/__init__.py
./apps/myapp/migrations/__init__.py
./apps/myapp/templatetags/__init__.py
./apps/myapp/management/__init__.py
./apps/myapp/management/commands/__init__.py
./settings/__init__.py
```

I’m running:

- ubuntu 14.04LTS latest
- in virtualenv
- Django==1.11.4

And I'm totally lost.

Comment: How are you referring to this app in INSTALLED_APPS?

Comment: Don't add `django.setup()` to your settings. You only need to call `django.setup()` when using Django in stand-alone scripts. You shouldn't need `from .admin import *` in your `__init__.py` file either.

Comment: `django.setup()` removed, tnx :) ... app reference was just `myapp` .. but also had `apps` added to syspath.